# Pushing an array inside another as a value

Tags: ruby, arrays, immutability

How do I append an array inside another array as a value and not as a reference? Below an illustrated example:

```
a = []
m = []
i = 1

# first loop
a[0] = i      
a[1] = i + 1
m << a #=> [[1,2]]

i += 1

# second loop
a[0] = i
a[1] = i + 1
m << a #=> [[2,3],[2,3]]
```

I expected something like `[[1,2],[2,3]]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to better understand what is going on here by examining the id's of the various objects.

```
a = []
a.object_id    #=> 2164985760
m = []
i = 1
```

*First loop*

```
a[0] = i       #=> 1      
a[1] = i + 1   #=> 2
a.object_id    #=> 2164985760
m << a         #=> [[1,2]]
m.object_id    #=> 2165031720
m[0].object_id #=> 2164985760
```

*Second loop*

```
i += 1
a[0] = i       #=> 2
a[1] = i + 1   #=> 3
a.object_id    #=> 2164985760
m << a         #=> [[2, 3], [2, 3]]
m.object_id    #=> 2165031720
m[0].object_id #=> 2164985760
m[1].object_id #=> 2164985760
```

Now let's try it again, with just one change.  As @sawa suggests, add `a = []` before the second loop.  (The following object ids will of course be different from those above.)

```
a = []
a.object_id     #=> 2164690760
m = []
i = 1
```

*First loop*

```
a[0] = i       #=> 1
a[1] = i + 1   #=> 2
a.object_id    #=> 2164690760
m << a         #=> [[1, 2]]
m.object_id    #=> 2164655180
m[0].object_id #=> 2164690760
```

*Second loop*

```
a = []
a.object_id    #=> 2161060600
i += 1         #=> 2
a[0] = i       #=> 2
a[1] = i + 1   #=> 3
a.object_id    #=> 2161060600
m << a         #=> [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
m.object_id    #=> 2164655180
m[0].object_id #=> 2164690760
m[1].object_id #=> 2161060600
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the first `m << a` with `m << a.dup`.  This will push a copy (or `dup`licate) of `a` onto `m`, which is different from `a`, so when you modify `a` you won't be modifying the object in `m`.  One way to see this is as follows:

```
a = []
m = []
m << a
a << 0
m #=> [[0]]

x = a.dup 
m << x
m #=> [[0], [0]]

a << 1
m #=> [[0, 1], [0]]

x << 2
m #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign `a` to another array.

```
m = []

i = 1
a = []
a[0] = i      
a[1] = i + 1
m << a

i += 1
a = []
a[0] = i
a[1] = i + 1
m << a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expected something like `[[1,2],[2,3]]` as a result after looping, you should probably be looking to use the Ruby functionality of `.map` to loop and return an array.

That way you wouldn't need to worry about managing the intermediate variables (or even, the counter in your example):

```
loop_count = 2 # or whatever currently determines how many loops you make
m = (1..loop_count).map do |i|
  [i, i+1]
end

m #=> [[1,2],[2,3]]
```